# How to transform heterogenous flat data to data structure

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, transformation

I am looking for a way to transform flat data to a data structure. The input for this transformation is not homogenous. Some data contain too much info, other data contain info that needs processing.

Let me explain with an example. Suppose I have some Excel files with car data. The files contain info about cars and their engines.

**File 1:**

```
Name | Type | EngineId | Manufacturer | Power (hp) | Torque
Opel | Adam | I4       | Opel         | 69         | 115
```

**File 2:**

```
Brand | Type  | Engine | Power (kW) | Manufacturer
Fiat  | Punto | 1.2-L  | 44         | Chrysler
```

As you can see, the files differ slightly: Name and Brand for the first column, different units of measure for Power, Manufacturer is at different positions and Torque is missing in File 2.

I'd like to transform this to something like:

```
public class Car {
    string Name;
    string Type;
    Engine Engine;
}

public class Engine {
    string Id;
    string Manufacturer;
    double Power; 
    Dictionary<string,string> OtherAttributes;
}
```

I think the transform needs classes for transformation rules as well:

```
public class MappingRules {
    string FileType; // File 1 vs File 2
    List<MappingRule> MappingRules;
}

public class MappingRule<T> {
    string SourceColumnName;
    string Target;
    ITranslate<T> Translator;
}

interface ITranslate<T> {
    T Convert(T sourceValue);
}
```

My problem is: how can I achieve this, but even more: how do I research this?

**Update**

I finally chose an approach in which the target structure is hard coded (i.e. the `Car` and `Engine` class). The user got a tool in which he, per file type, maps the columns to the properties of those classes. A translator then translates the values in the columns to the properties in the classes.

Comment: This would at least be a start on researching the topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cleansing, but I expect it's not all that helpful for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right.  For each file you need to define how it transforms into your object.  If each file is independent of each other, they can be converted in any order.  If there are missing fields, you need to define what is value they should get.

If you want to do it directly from java, check out the **apache-POI** library, or export it to CSV for processing.

The more extensive way is to convert it to XML so that any tool will know how to process it using some XSL transformations.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It helped finding a suitable solution.

Answer (score 3):

That's how I'd do that, more or less:

1. Create data models for each of the file types. Write deserialization of the files into those data models.
2. For each of those models, create a conversion into your common model. This can for example be done either inside of each of those (e.g. making them implement an interface).
3. Basing on the file type, instantiate appropriate model and load from the file, then use the conversion utility.

Your "transformation rules" idea is something that lies outside of that part of the design, as in, it's a detail of the conversion functions' implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using XML, XSL & JAXB for this in the following way -

1. Read the flat files into XML with attribute as the  and
   value of the attribute as value of the tag i.e.  value
   . For example  Opel . You can use
   StringTokenizer with token as '|' for this
2. Now use XPATH and XSLT to map from your source XML structure to target XML structure
3. Once you have XMLs in the target format, then use JAXB to load the values of the XML into their equivalent Object Content Tree ( Note
   for using JAXB you will need to generate the Classes which make up
   the content tree in advance for which you will need to define XML
   Schemas(XSD) for your target XML structures first)

Comment: Thanks for the input. My solution had to have more flexibility than your approach though.